# Tor node IP list update service been stopped recently?

Tags: node

The "torbulkexitlist" which was updated every day, has not changed the contents of the recent Tor IP list..

I would like to ask if the service has been permanently suspended or temporarily suspended.

URI : https://check.torproject.org/torbulkexitlist?ip=1.1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this link](https://blog.torproject.org/changes-tor-exit-list-service/) for information on how the Tor Exit List works.

From the blog post:

> Exit lists are provided through three interfaces: raw measurement
> results are archived by CollecTor, a text file containing all exit
> addresses is available for download to query locally, and finally, we
> provide a DNS exit list service to allow services to perform real-time
> lookups.

This is where you can see the [latest list](https://metrics.torproject.org/collector/recent/exit-lists/). It is updated daily.